# How to summarize by calculated measure in Power BI?

Tags: dax

I have transactional data which contains customer information as well as stores they shopped from. I can count the number of different stores each customer used by a simple `DISTINCTCOUNT([Site Name])` measure.

There are millions of customers and I want to make a simple summary table which shows the sum of # customers who visited X number of stores. Like a histogram. Maximum stores they visited is 6, minimum is 1.

I know there are multiple ways to do this but I am new to DAX and can't do what I think yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way:

1. Assuming your `DISTINCTCOUNT([Site Name])` measure is called `CustomerStoreCount` ...
2. Add a new dimension table, `StoreCount`, to your model containing a single column, `StoreCount`. Populate it with the values 1,2,3,4,5,6 (... up to maximum number of stores.)
3. Create a measure, `ThisStoreCount = MAX(StoreCount[StoreCount])`.
4. Create a base customer count measure, `TotalCustomers:=DISTINCTCOUNT(CustomerTable[Customer])`
5. Create a contextual measure, `CustomersWhoVisitedXNumberOfStores := CALCULATE ( TotalCustomers, FILTER(VALUES(CustomerTable[Customer]), ThisStoreCount = CustomerStoreCount) )`
6. On your pivot table / reporting tool, etc. use `StoreCount[StoreCount]` on the axes and `CustomersWhOVisitedXNumberOfStores` as the measure.

So basically walk through the customer list (since there's no relationship between `StoreCount` and `CustomerTable`), compare that customer's `CustomerStoreCount` with the maximum `StoreCount[StoreCount]` value, which for each `StoreCount[StoreCount]` value is  ... *drum roll* itself. If it matches, keep it, otherwise filter it out; you end up with a count of customers whose store visits equals the value of `StoreCount[StoreCount]`.

And of course the more general modeling hint: when you want to display a metric *by* **something** (i.e. customer count *by* number of stores visited), that **something** is an *attribute*, not a metric.